# Walking a tree asynchronously in Node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion, tree

I'm trying to write a function in Node to recursively retrieve Wikipedia category trees. Given a parent tree, it should call the API, get a category, then get the category's subcategories, etc, down to the end of the branches.

That's relatively straight-forward in a synchronous language, but recursion + async is tripping me up.

I've got a simple function `call` to phone the [MediaWiki API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) and get the categorymembers response for any object, which returns both pages in that category and subcategories in that category. ([Here's an example response](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3aUniversity_of_Arkansas_alumni&format=json&cmlimit=500).)

If `call` was synchronous, I would just do something like this:

```
var categoryTree = function(category, tree) {
    if (!tree) {
        tree = {
            name: category,
            pages: [],
            subcategories: []
        };
    }

    var children = call(category);
    category.query.categorymembers.forEach(function(child) {
        // if it's a page
        var node = { name: child.title };
        if (child.ns == 0) {
            tree.pages.push(node);
        } else {
                    // if it's a subcat
            tree.subcategories.push(call(categoryTree(node.name, node)));               
        }
    });
    return tree;
}
```

But it's not, of course. The `call` function uses `request`, so it takes the arguments `(category, callback)`. So far I've got something like this:

```
var categoryTree = function(category, callback, data, node) {
    call(category, cb);

    if (!data) {
        data = {};
        node = data;
    }

    function cb(members) {
        node.pages = [];
        node.subcategories = [];

        members.query.categorymembers.forEach(function(member) {
            var new_node = {
                name: member.title                   
            }
            if (member.ns == 14) {
                node.subcategories.push(new_node);
                categoryTree(member.title, callback, data, new_node);
            } else if (member.ns == 0) {
                node.pages.push(new_node);
            }
        });

        callback(data);
    }
}
```

This obviously isn't right. Is it possible to do an async recursive tree walk?

Comment: isn't `call` a reserved word? hmm [guess not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) but as `.call` is a built in `Function` method i suggest you rename that.

Comment: you may want to utilize the `async` library, probably [`async.until`](https://github.com/caolan/async#untiltest-fn-callback`) testing whether there are any items in your current array

Comment: Wikipedia categories do not (have to) form a tree... Nothing prevents you from joining descendant branches (category X belongs to categories F and Q, which both belong to A). Possibly you can even form a loop (but I'm not so sure about that...)